# AutoHotkey: Hold down key while true

Tags: while-loop, autohotkey, keypress

**What it should do** 
z -> `SetTimer, loop, -1` 
loop -> 
`IfWinActive` -> press key 
`!IfWinActive` -> release key 

My Code:

```
#SingleInstance Force

z::
    SetTimer, loop, -1
return

loop:
    IfWinActive, Minecraft 1.8.9 | LabyMod 3.6.13
    {
        ; Press key aslong true
    }
return
```

But I simply not know how to simulate a key press aslong something is true

#### **Edit:**

Now I have this 
It loops `loop` until i press z again

```
loop :=0

z::
    if (GetKeyState("w"))
    { ; turns the loop off if w is already pressed
        loop :=0
        SetTimer, loop, Off
        Send {w} ; send w again so you stop running why ever minecraft is like that
    }
    else
    {
        loop :=1
        SetTimer, loop, 1
    }
return

loop:
    while (loop)
    {
        IfWinActive, Minecraft 1.8.9 | LabyMod 3.6.13
        {
            Send % "{w Down}"
        }
        IfWinNotActive, Minecraft 1.8.9 | LabyMod 3.6.13
        {
            Send % "{w Up}"
        }
    }
return
```

But the problem is it constantly presses `w up` or `w down`
if i wanny tab out the game it becomes buggy because i cant do a shortcut because it keeps interrupted by `w down`. it should only press `w down` until i tab out then it should press `w up` until i go in minecraft again

Comment: When you say `;Press key aslong true`, do you mean hold down that key, or repeatedly press and release the key?

Comment: @Spyre i mean holding down the keys

Answer (score 1):

(tested) setting timer to -1 doesn't work for some reason replace (key) with the actual key to hold down

```
z::
    SetTimer, loop, 1
return

loop:
    IfWinActive, Minecraft 1.8.9 | LabyMod 3.6.13
    {
        send {(key) down}
    } else {
        send {(key) up}
    }

return
```

Answer (score 0):

(fixed) i see your right you can't alt tab out of anything but you can make it stop when you press alt or tab like this. (also this is really useful i'm going to be using this in the future)

```
loop := 0
z::
    if (GetKeyState("w"))
    { ; turns the loop off if w is already pressed
        loop := 0
        SetTimer, loop, Off
        Send {w} ; send w again so you stop running why ever minecraft is like that
    }
    else
    {
        loop := 1
        SetTimer, loop, 1
    }
return

loop:
    while (loop)
    {
        IfWinActive, Minecraft 1.8.9 | LabyMod 3.6.13
        {
            if (GetKeyState("w")) Not {
            Send % "{w Down}"
            }
        }
        IfWinActive, Minecraft 1.8.9 | LabyMod 3.6.13
        {
            if (GetKeyState("w")) {
            Send % "{w Up}"
            }
        }
    }
return
!tab::
sleep, 100
send {d up}
send {alt down}
send {tab}
send {alt up}
return
```

you can change pressing down to this in to make it auto sprint!

```
{
            if (GetKeyState("w")) Not {
                sleep, 100
            Send % "{w Down}"
            sleep, 50
            Send % "{w Up}"
            sleep, 50
            Send % "{w Down}"
            }
        }
```

Comment: strange i tested on my minecraft and it doesn't work trying to fix it

Comment: uh oh i did some tests and the alt tab hotkey won't call when the loop is running and i can't press shift?!

Comment: what did you change

Comment: i dont under stand the second code. what you mean with autosprint? i use ctrl to sprint

Comment: double tapping w makes you sprint also

Comment: right xd forgot it. but is there any need? i though ctrl does the think

Comment: oh shot i forgot my new code presses ctrl all the time too

Comment: i really appreciate your code, but i wanted something that sends `w up` only once and doesnt spam it all the time and also doesnt spam `w down` when in minecraft

Comment: it already does it checks if it is already held down and if so doesn't press again

Comment: sorry i didnt see it. thanks for your code. i will link your stack profile in my github repo